# Did Timothy Zahn name Grand Admiral Thrawn after himself?

Tags: star-wars, names

It's always struck me that Grand Admiral Thrawn's name rhymes with that of his creator, Timothy Zahn. Thrawn also doesn't seem to be based on anything in English or anything else I'm familiar with. Was Thrawn meant to sound a lot like Zahn, or is there some other reason he got that name and it's just a coincidence that his name is so similar to the author?

Comment: Zahn (zaarn) and thrawn (thr-awe-n) don't sound especially similar in English

Comment: I've seen comments on [various boards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AGrand_Admiral_Thrawn) that Zahn was aware of the meaning of "thrawn" as a scots word meaning twisted. Allegedly he made those comments in the annotation of the 20th Anniversary Edition of Heir to the Empire. I've read through it and I can't find any confirmation in that book though.

Comment: In British RP, maybe the names are distinct as you say. In many American dialects, there is no /a/ in Zahn, and the /ɔ/ and /a/ [have merged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot%E2%80%93caught_merger). Thrawn is pronounced /θran/ and Zahn is pronounced /zan/, and they are perfect rhymes.

Comment: Next thing you'll tell me that Luke S. was based on the name of someone too.

Comment: @Adamant - In the early drafts he was Lucas Starkiller.

Comment: @Valorum: Actually, he was called *Anakin* Starkiller. There was an elderly general called Luke Skywalker, though.

Comment: @KlausÆMogensen - Before that

Comment: Ridiculous suggestion. Zahn clearly came up with the name "Grand Admiral Timothy Thrawn" through pure imagination.

Comment: I'd only believe it if Thrawn's first name turns out to be Blimothy.

Comment: @Valorum You're kidding, right? I've lived in the US my whole life and speak fluent English. Is Zahn not pronounced how it looks like? Kind of like Han but with a z.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe - Zahn rhymes with tarn. Thrawn rhymes with prawn. Simples; https://youtu.be/18WFA3GvJAE?t=242

Comment: @Valorum - Prawn rhymes with Zahn in a lot of US dialects. And for what it's worth, I think they clearly said /zaaan/. No /r/ in there. But since RP and most English dialects are non-rhotic it probably sounds like the way many English people would say Zarn.

Comment: [This](https://youglish.com/pronounce/yarn/english/us?) elucidating. One can contrast the British and American.

Comment: @Valorum not In Iowa it don't. There's no R. Here in Zahn rhymes with Han and Lawn.